# Ajax POST - display response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would to display a response body of Ajax POST request on my page:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<url>",
    data: jsonText,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "text/plain",
    contentType : "application/json",

    //if received a response from the server
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(response);
            $("#uploadResponse").innerHtml = response;
    },

    });
```

I get response with response but the success function is not triggered and I see not output. Why is that?

Comment: Have you enabled CORS on your API? The behaviour sounds like you're being blocked by the Same Origin Policy

Comment: Is it successful? Check your console for more info?

Comment: Yes, I have - I get the response with 200 - just no body in it.

Comment: Have you enabled all the error logging in ASP.net?

Comment: Ok, I just noticed that the body is in there - it is just not displayed so the success function is not triggered. I will edit my question

Comment: In that case I'm certain that the SOP is preventing the data received by the request be accessed in your JS code. You need to enable CORS on your Spring API: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: CORS is enabled. If I insect the response in developer console in my browser, everything is there. I just cannot seem to figure out how to display it with javascript

Comment: Is there any issue with the async call?

Comment: The result is probably not in text/plain format. Try to catch the error using error: callback function. Also try changing the dataType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jQuery objects can't have DOM methods and jQuery methods can't be applied on raw DOM elements as well. So you need to apply jQuery method to jQuery object and vice versa.

And one thing to be noticed `innerHTML` is the actual method not `innerHtml`.

Either do this:

```
$("#uploadResponse")[0].innerHTML = response;
```

or within jQuery:

```
$("#uploadResponse").html(response); // or .text(response);
```

---

The `dataType` is seemingly doubtful change to `dataType:"text"` only.

Comment: Nothing happens after getting the response. I see it in my browser console with all the data I need but no alert or html append is triggered

Comment: @Smajl i am not sure about your dataType, change to `dataType: "text",` only.